# Back button in programmatically created Views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have few screens draw programmatically, and i want to add a back button in my UINavigationBar. So i think of something like that:
I have a class that inherits from UIViewController - myViewController. So i've made an Array where i store my views (myViewController class objects), and back button simply reload the current screen content to previous screen from array. Is that a good way for doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what `UINavigationController` is for.  Use that.

Also:

> So i've made an Array where i store my views (myViewController class objects)

Views and view controllers are entirely different things.  If you mix them up, you're going to have lots of problems.

Comment: I think I don't mix them up. I have one UIViewController for a screen and few UIViews, UITableViews... Based on: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/CreatingViews/CreatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH5-SW1 So question.. If I have a few screens I may want to have them on stack? Create separate view for it?

Comment: You are mixing them up.  You can't solve this by creating a separate view to be used as a stack of view controllers.  **Use `UINavigationController`.  That's what it's for.**